# Shopware 6 variant images (covers) missing / not showing in variant selection

Tags: shopware6

I have a Shopware 6 system running with multiple products. Some of them has variants. These variants are shown as I would expect.

Now I switched the `displayType` to `image` for this variant group. And now some of my variants do not show the image in the variant picker on the right (in frontend) while the cover images to this variant are existing and gets shown when selecting this variant.

Debugging the `media` variable in `configurator.html.twig` where the variant image gets rendered show on the variants with missing images `false` – on other variants the object of the media and the images gets shown. I cannot find any difference between variants with and without image – both have images applied and set the correct one as cover image. Also when I try to change the image on a variant which shows an image right now the image in variant picker do not change.

I also tried re-generating all thumbnails in the whole project via CLI. Also no effect.

Clearing caches did not do anything.

I also saved one of the missing images in variants and reexported from Photoshop for web (JPG) und replaced it. Also no effect.

**How can I update the variant images when changing the cover-images in variants do not take any effect?**

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting `displayType` of the entity `property_group`, the image type refers to media associated to `property_group_options`, **not** the images of a product. For example if you have a property group "Material", you can choose the display type image and then set an image to each option of that group, e.g. a closeup photograph of the texture of each material.

To have an image of the actual product you would navigate to when selecting a variant, you would have to create a custom extension.